Anotation after filter (freeze queryset) Django
In the process of model annotation there is a need to filter the finished list. But the value of the annotation "rank" after the filter() becomes "1" because it has only one element. Without filtering the queryset everything works fine
request_user = (
            MainUser.objects.select_related("balance_account")
            .annotate(coin_balance=F("balance_account__coin_balance"))
            .annotate(rank=Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by="-coin_balance"))
            .filter(id=data.get("user_id"))
            .first()
        )

Is there a way to avoid the race or freeze the filtered queryset?
qs = set(
      MainUser.objects.select_related("balance_account")
     .annotate(coin_balance=F("balance_account__coin_balance"))  
     .annotate(rank=Window(expression=RowNumber(), 
      order_by="-coin_balance"))
     )
q = list(filter(lambda x: x.id == data.get("user_id"), qs))[0]

But how optimal is this approach?
